# Site preview is showing for all links on my Plesk site

Tags: links, plesk

I have a website that is hosted with Plesk Control Panel. All my links show some site preview prepended to it. I don't know what I should do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you have run some kind of CMS installer through the site preview link. the installer has set the host name based on the link you where using to access the site at the time. the CMS system you are using should have the hostname set in a config file or admin panel that you can change from the preview URL to the correct domain URL.

You can avoid using preview links by editing your local host file to force your own machine to go to a particular ip before you change the DNS records. on a windows machine it will be in C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts you simply put the domain name and the ip you want it to resolve to (your Plesk server). This also stops rewrite rules breaking when previewing a site.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't update the DNS records for your site yet, just use the Plesk site preview option to see whether your site is working or not.